# Are the Bluetooth and Wi-Fi MAC addresses assigned in the same address space?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, bluetooth, mac-address

Are the MAC addresses of Wi-Fi, Ethernet and Bluetooth devices assigned in the same address space? Or are MAC address unique irrespective of the physical layer? Is there a possibility of MAC address collision if Wi-Fi (or Ethernet) and Bluetooth devices reused the MAC address? While routers bridge WLAN and Ethernet LAN, I have not seen any device that bridges Bluetooth and LAN (Ethernet or WLAN). Do such devices exist?

Comment: You seems to have multiple questions.  How about pick one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're all IEEE EUI-48's (EUI == Extended Unique Identifier), and the IEEE Registration Authority manages the address space to guarantee uniqueness. The first 24 bits is an Organizationally Unique Identifier (OUI). Each OUI is assigned to a particular company by the IEEE. That company can then make 2^24 unique MAC addresses with that OUI as the prefix. It's the company's responsibility to make sure they never program the same MAC address onto more than one device or interface.

Comment: If MACs were reused - by say a student working on a project, can there be a possible collision between Bluetooth, WLAN and ethernet?

Comment: @LordLoh. Yes there can.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a gateway that bridges a Bluetooth and LAN / WLAN? I could not find any. Thank you for the answer :-)